# Installing a plugin in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am trying to install the state_select plugin. I tried rails plugin install  and rails can't find it no matter how I enter the path with require.

I tried to use bundler using gem "state_select", :git => "git://github.com/bansalakhil/state_select.git" but there is no gem for it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. The owner of state_select claims it works on Rails 3 (http://www.railsplugins.org/plugins/293-state-select).

I just tried it out in Rails 3 and it seems to work. The main trouble I had was installing it, because when I ran

```
rails plugin install https://github.com/zdennis/state_select.git
```

(I'm not sure if zdennis is the right one but it's just an example), I got this error:

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref HEAD
```

You can work around it by downloading the ZIP file and expanding it with the name "state_plugin" in vendor/plugins. Then put this in a view, without any "require" statement:

```
<%= state_select(:us, {}) %>
```

It shows a state dropdown in the view.